# Error on start Ember project on new machine: Unexpected token import, define is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, webpack, babeljs

I have existing Ember js project on 2 computers, but I have problems with installation on a new one.

I do install on such way:

```
git clone <repository-url>
cd projectfolder
npm install
bower install
ember serve
```

It compiles but on browser I see such errors:

> event-factory.js:3 - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
>
> application.js:1 - Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined

Seems like some error with babel.

I have such package.json

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "private": true,
  "directories": {
    "doc": "doc",
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "ember build",
    "start": "ember server",
    "test": "ember test"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "..."
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.12.0"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "broccoli-asset-rev": "^2.4.5",
    "ember-ajax": "2.4.1",
    "ember-cli": "^2.10.0",
    "ember-cli-app-version": "^2.0.0",
    "ember-cli-babel": "^5.1.7",
    "ember-cli-data-export": "0.1.26",
    "ember-cli-dependency-checker": "^1.3.0",
    "ember-cli-deploy": "*",
    "ember-cli-deploy-build": "*",
    "ember-cli-deploy-gzip": "*",
    "ember-cli-deploy-revision-data": "*",
    "ember-cli-deploy-s3": "*",
    "ember-cli-deploy-ssh-index": "*",
    "ember-cli-google-fonts": "1.13.0",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars": "^1.0.10",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile": "^0.3.3",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.4.1",
    "ember-cli-jshint": "^2.0.1",
    "ember-cli-moment-shim": "1.2.0",
    "ember-cli-pagination": "2.2.3",
    "ember-cli-qunit": "^3.0.1",
    "ember-cli-release": "0.2.9",
    "ember-cli-sri": "^2.1.0",
    "ember-cli-test-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "ember-cli-uglify": "^1.2.0",
    "ember-content-editable": "0.10.0",
    "ember-data": "^2.10.0",
    "ember-data-change-tracker": "0.5.5",
    "ember-disable-proxy-controllers": "^1.0.1",
    "ember-export-application-global": "^1.0.5",
    "ember-load-initializers": "^0.5.1",
    "ember-metrics": "0.8.1",
    "ember-notify": "^5.2.0",
    "ember-power-select": "1.0.0",
    "ember-radio-button": "1.1.1",
    "ember-resolver": "^2.0.3",
    "ember-select-guru": "^1.1.2",
    "ember-simple-auth": "1.1.0",
    "ember-simple-auth-loopback": "1.1.0",
    "ember-truth-helpers": "1.2.0",
    "ember-welcome-page": "^1.0.3",
    "loader.js": "^4.0.10",
    "mock-socket": "^6.0.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ember-cli": "^2.11.1",
    "ember-cli-babel": "^5.2.4",
    "ember-cli-deploy": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-cli-deploy-gzip": "^0.2.4",
    "ember-cli-deploy-revision-data": "^0.3.3",
    "ember-cli-deploy-s3": "^0.4.0",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.6.1",
    "ember-cli-qunit": "^3.1.1",
    "ember-data": "^2.11.3",
    "ember-websockets": "6.3.0",
    "loader.js": "^4.2.2"
  }
}
```

and bower.json:

```
{
  "name": "getprospect",
  "dependencies": {
    "ember": "v2.10.2",
    "ember-cli-shims": "0.1.3",
    "ember-cli-test-loader": "0.2.2",
    "ember-qunit-notifications": "0.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "jquery-stupid-table": "^1.0.1",
    "jquery-auto-grow-input": "*",
    "file-saver": "*",
    "js-xlsx": "~0.8.0",
    "fullcalendar": "^2.7.1",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.11",
    "ember-simple-auth": "^0.8.0",
    "raven-js": "^3.2.1",
    "urijs": "^1.18.8",
    "socket.io-client": "^1.7.2"
  }
}
```

I've successfully installed this project some month ago, but can't figure out why is not launching on this machine... Any help appreciated.

Comment: can you try the following please: in one of the machines where your code is already working, please copy and save `node_modules` and `bower_components` to a safe place. then delete those two directories and run `npm install` and `bower install`. i suspect that it will also start failing. what i think is there are `^` symbols in your `package.json` that will upgrade your dependencies to newer versions in case you perform a clean install. this might be the reason why your code is failing. you can remove those `^` or use `~` and try again. can you try and give an update so that we can help more.

Comment: thank you for writing this @alptugd, I also have same issue. I thought it was an ember-cli-babel due to how "import" was not transpiled to ES5, but it was not enough. I ended up removing hat (^) from all packages and it worked. Will need more time to figure out what package actually causes it for my ember app. (ember-cli 2.9.1)

Comment: @GogromaT you can make use of `npm outdated` to figure out which dependencies are outdated and focus on these ones.

Comment: @alptugd Yes, you're right. It's a correct answer. Thank you. I've removed ^ and project launched. You can port your answer, I'll mark it as solution.

Comment: @Dmytro I have wrapped the comments in here as an answer, thanks for your kindness. best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you had is most probably using `^` for your dependencies. What `^` (caret) does is upgrading your dependencies to a major version when you do a clean install. For instance if your dependency to an addon is let's say `1.2.0` and you used `^1.2.0` and there is a new version available `1.3.0`, you will get this new major version. If you use `~` (tilda) instead of `^`, then you will not get `1.3.0` but `1.2.2` for instance if available. In order to use the exact versions so that your dependencies will not change when you do a clean `npm install`, you can remove both caret and tilda in your dependency definitions.

In order to figure out which of your dependencies is outdated you can use `npm outdated`.